# Why is my form not retrieving any data in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to combine two input json data for a class based django rest framework view.
I am feeding in data in this format

```
{
    "profile": {
        "phone": "9841101115",
        "email": "nirjalpaudl543sddsd12@gmail.com",
        "bio": "I am the admin of the site",
        "status": "AWY",
        "address": "Pepsicola, Kathmandu"
    },
    "user": {
        "username": "sampanna12",
        "password1": "test12345",
        "password2": "test12345"
    }
}
```

The error shown suggests that data was never retrieved by the serializers. The response i get is

```
{
    "Error": "Something went wrong while making a user",
    "message": {
        "username": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "password1": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "password2": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

My post view is getting the data but my form is not getting as suggested by the response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55T17.png)
My models.py looks like

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user         = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile_user")
    email        = models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=False,unique=True)
    bio          = models.TextField(verbose_name="Describe Yourself")
    statustypes  =  (
                        ("LFJ","Looking for job"),
                        ("CAJ","Creating a job"),
                        ("AWY","Away for somtime"),
                    )
    status       = models.CharField(choices=statustypes,max_length=3,blank=False)
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    address      = models.CharField(max_length=40,)
    #cv          = models.OneToOneField(CV,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #pp           = models.ImageField(verbos_name="Profile Picture",upload_to="profile pictures")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My serializer.py looks like

```py
from rest_framework import serializers 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import models 

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    password1=serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        min_length=8,
        required=True,
        style={
            "input_type":"password"
        }
    )

    password2=serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        min_length=8,
        required=True,
        style={
            "input_type":"password"
        }
    )
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=["username","password1","password2"]    



class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=models.Profile
        fields=['phone','email','bio','status','address','user']
```

My views.py looks like

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import APIView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import serializers,models
# Create your views here.

class UserApi(APIView):
    def get(self,request, format=None):
        allusers=models.Profile.objects.all()
        print(allusers)
        data=serializers.ProfileSerializer(allusers,many=True)
        return Response(data.data)

    def post(self,request, format=None):
        data=request.data
        print(data.get("user"))
        print(data.get("profile"))
        sampleprofile=serializers.ProfileSerializer( data=data.get("user") )
        sampleuser=serializers.UserSerializer( data=data.get("profile") )
        if sampleuser.is_valid():
            currentuser=sampleuser.create()
        else:
            return Response({
                    "Error":"Something went wrong while making a user",
                    "message":sampleuser.errors,
                })

        sampleprofile.user=sampleuser

        if sampleprofile.is_valid():
            sampleprofile.create()
        else:
            return Response({
                    "Error":"Something went wrong while making profile",
                    "message":sampleprofile.errors,
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to pass the user-data to the `ProfileSerializer` and the profile data to the `UserSerializer`. I think, changing:

```
sampleprofile=serializers.ProfileSerializer( data=data.get("user") )
sampleuser=serializers.UserSerializer( data=data.get("profile") )
```

to:

```
sampleprofile=serializers.ProfileSerializer( data=data.get("profile") )
sampleuser=serializers.UserSerializer( data=data.get("user") )
```

is going to solve the issue.